# How get correct path for import through alias?

Tags: webpack

I added alias in webpack.config. And this is working, styles importing fine. But editors (Webstorm, VSCode) highlight this paths: "Cannot resolve directory".

How fix this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[WebStorm is designed to integrate with Webpack automatically](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/using-webpack.html#specify_webpack_configuration_file), but sometimes you need to point it to the file where you define your aliases manually.
You can do that by going to `Settings > Languages & Framework > JavaScript > Webpack`, choose "Manually" and then select your `webpack.config` file.

Example from my setup - after pointing WebStorm to the file where the aliases are defined, it correctly resolves my aliases:
[image: webpack config webstorm]